# noexcept, __declspec(nothrow), throw(), __attribute__(nothrow)

Tags: c++

What's the purpose of using modifiers like `noexcept`, `__declspec(nothrow)`, `throw()`, `__attribute__(nothrow)` and probably a few more all with different semantics, different compiler support and alleged pros and cons? When I try adding any of those in my code I'm still getting the same assembly.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/) seems to imply that *some* compilers can in *some cases* optimize based on this information. I imagine that the compiler can avoid some amount work but only in highly specific cases.

That same article seems to suggest that *not* explicitly using the keyword is a fine path to choose because of how specific the use case is.